# Write to CRM footer with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I've noticed that when a mandatory field is not completed and a user attempts to save it adds a message to the form footer

Is it possible to do the same with JavaScript? For example, if I have a custom validation logic that fails (e.g. Start Date must occur within 6 months), is it possible and how would I add a validation message in the same location?

[image: Default behavior]

Comment: "can I add a validation message in the same location?" If this is your only question, the answer is yes.

Comment: @marekful it would be nice to have a bit more of an explanation of how this is possible. I don't want to resort to DOM manipulation for example

Answer (score 3):

[This (MSDN link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_notification) is the supported way of displaying custom notifications, similar to the ones that come up for required fields.

The linked MSDN is too long to copy-paste here, essentially we're looking at these functions:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(arg).setNotification
Xrm.Page.getControl(arg).addNotification
Xrm.Page.getControl(arg).clearNotification
```

Answer (score 0):

[Business rule](https://onemichaelscott.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/displaying-messages-to-the-user-in-dynamics-crm-2013/) can help. 
 But you may need one more calculated field to achieve your need.